# Django's authentication form is always not valid

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I was trying to implement a basic login system using Django with a custom user using the AbstractUser class.
Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Stock(models.Model):
    stock_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    stock_price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stock_name

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    stocks = models.ManyToManyField(Stock)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

My forms.py:

```
from .models import CustomUser,Stock
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class loginform(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

My views.py:

```
def successful_login(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=pk)
    return render(request, '../templates/stock_portfolio.html', {'user':user})

def loginview(request):
    err=0
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = loginform(request.POST)
        pdb.set_trace()
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                pdb.set_trace()
                login(request, user)
                pk = user.id
                pdb.set_trace()
                return redirect('successful_login', pk=pk)
        else:
            err=1
            return render(request,'../templates/login.html',{'response':err,'form':form})
    else:
        form = loginform()
    return render(request, '../templates/login.html',{'form':form})
```

While logging using pdb here is what I am getting for the form.

```
<loginform bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;password)>
```

How do I proceed now?

Comment: look on `form.data` then if all ok, do `form.is_valid()`, and look on `form.errors`

Comment: Checked it form .data returns {} and form.is_valid() still returns False.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Answering this since I just had the same issue and found the problem. Change your

```
form = loginform(request.POST)
```

to

```
form = loginform(data=request.POST)
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks very much!

Comment: Oh man, just found this after hours of searching... I must have missed it in the docs!

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why `data` works?

Comment: it does not work for me which django version is that I am using 2.2.23

Comment: This also worked for me, is it just a problem with the AuthenticationForm specifically? Or do all forms need this? how come i don't have to do this with any other form?

Answer (score 0):

Like dfundako answered, you should pass request.POST as data directly `loginform(data=request.POST)`

But the **reason** is that default django AuthenticationForm in `__init__` has first argument `request` instead of data as usual:

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
"""
Base class for authenticating users. Extend this to get a form that accepts
username/password logins.
"""

...
...


def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
    The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.
    """
    self.request = request
    self.user_cache = None
```

Therefore, in fact, when you write `loginform(request.POST)` - you pass request.POST data like a request argument, so basically it should look like
`loginform(request, request.POST)`